# Virtual reality sdk iOS for rendering Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, ios9, google-cardboard, 360-virtual-reality

Can you suggest what all open-source virtual reality SDKs available for iOS platform. I want to load Google Maps into virtual reality using Google Cardboard.

When I search the web for it, I am only finding for augumented reality sdks.

Answer (score 1):

There's now an official Cardboard SDK for iOS
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/ios/